# Wrap exceptions by runtime exceptions with an annotation

Tags: java, exception, annotations, runtimeexception

Is there a way to annotate a method so all exceptions thrown are converted to runtime exception automagically?

```
@MagicAnnotation
// no throws clause!
void foo()
{
  throw new Exception("bar")'
}
```

Comment: iow a way to turn off the compiler checks on checked exceptions.

Comment: Yes - I think I saw this somewhere, even in our own codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do that, at least for now I use workaround like this (simplified):

```
@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
public class Unchecked {
    public static interface UncheckedDefinitions{
        InputStream openStream();
        String readLine();
            ...
    }

  private static Class proxyClass = Proxy.getProxyClass(Unchecked.class.getClassLoader(), UncheckedDefinitions.class);

    public static UncheckedDefinitions unchecked(final Object target){
        try{
            return (UncheckedDefinitions) proxyClass.getConstructor(InvocationHandler.class).newInstance(new InvocationHandler(){
                @Override
                public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                    if (target instanceof Class){
                        return MethodUtils.invokeExactStaticMethod((Class) target, method.getName(), args);
                    }

                  return MethodUtils.invokeExactMethod(target, method.getName(), args);
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And the usage looks like:

```
import static ....Unchecked.*;

...

Writer w = ...;
unchecked(w).write(str, off, len);
```

The trick is that interface is "never finished" and everytime I need unchecked method somewhere, I'll wrap that object into unchecked and let IDE generate method signature in interface.

Implementation is then generic (reflective and "slow" but usually fast enough)

There are some code post-processors and bytecode-weavers but this was not possible (not even aop or other jvm based language) for my current project, so this was "invented".

Answer (score 8):

Project Lombok's [`@SneakyThrows`](http://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows.html) is probably what you are looking for. Is not really wrapping your exception (because it can be a problem in a lot of cases), it just doesn't throw an error during compilation.

```
@SneakyThrows
void foo() {
    throw new Exception("bar")'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with AspectJ. You declare a joinpoint (in this case invocation of the method foo) and 'soften' the exception.

**Edit** To elaborate a bit on this:

Say you have the following class `Bar`:

```
public class Bar {

    public void foo() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

...and you have a test like this:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class BarTest extends TestCase {

    public void testTestFoo() {
        new Bar().foo();
    }
}
```

Then obviously the test is not going to compile. It will give an error:

```
Unhandled exception type Exception  BarTest.java(line 6)
```

Now to overcome this with AspectJ, you write a very simple aspect:

```
public aspect SoftenExceptionsInTestCode {

    pointcut inTestCode() : execution(void *Test.test*());

    declare soft : Exception : inTestCode();
}
```

The aspect basically says that any code from within a Test (i.e.: a method that starts with "test" in a class that ends in "Test" and returns 'void') that throws an exception should be accepted by the AspectJ compiler. If an exception occurs, it will be wrapped and thrown as a `RuntimeException` by the AspectJ compiler.

Indeed, if you run this test as part of an AspectJ project from within Eclipse (with AJDT installed) then the test will succeed, whereas without the aspect it won't even compile.

Comment: I think this is a fair answer (although I don't know anything about AOP besides the concepts). Wonder why it was downvoted?

Comment: Sample code would be very nice - there are many new concepts when looking on AOP which is hard to get right.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible with bytecode re-engineering, customized compiler or perhaps aspect oriented programming<sup>1</sup>. In the contrary to Java, C# has only unchecked exceptions<sup>2</sup>.

May I ask why you want to suppress the checked exceptions?

<sup>1</sup> according to *Maarten Winkels* this is possible.
<sup>2</sup> and they are thinking about introducing checked ones, according to some Channel 9 videos.

**Edit:** For the question: It is possible in the sense that you can annotate your methods to flag them to be a candidate for checked exception suppression. Then you use some compile time or runtime trick to apply the actual suppression / wrapping.

However, as I don't see the environment around your case, wrapping an exception in these ways might confuse the clients of that method - they might not be prepared to deal with a RuntimeException. For example: the method throws an IOException and your clients catches it as FileNotFoundException to display an error dialog. However if you wrap your exception into a RuntimeException, the error dialog gets never shown and probably it kills the caller thread too. (IMHO).

Comment: Test code, I don't really care about which exceptions at that point.

Also, my take in the checked-exceptions-yes-or-no is a rather solid No (but will conform to standard and not have all my exceptions extend RuntimeException for production code).

Comment: Thank you. I think having the option for use checked exception is good - it allows you to 'guide' your clients. However, I sometimes feel it too, in some particular cases, that an exception should have been the other type. Still, on conceptional level, I think my answer still stands.

Answer (score 1):

The Checked exceptions are responsability of the method implementation.
Take very very carefully this fact. if you can do not use workaround artifacts like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in any case via use of the fact that `Class.newInstance` *does not* wrap an `Exception` thrown by the no-arg constructor in an `InvocationTargetException`; rather it throws it *silently*:

```
class ExUtil {
  public static void throwSilent(Exception e) { //NOTICE NO THROWS CLAUSE
      tl.set(e);
      SilentThrower.class.newInstance(); //throws silently
  }

  private static ThreadLocal<Exception> tl = new ThreadLocal<Exception>();
  private static class SilentThrower {
      SilentThrower() throws Exception {
          Exception e = tl.get();
          tl.remove();
          throw e;
      }
  }
}
```

Then you can use this utility anywhere:

```
ExUtil.throwSilent(new Exception());
//or
try {
  ioMethod();
} catch (IOException e) { ExUtil.throwSilent(e); }
```

By the way, this is **a really bad idea** :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use the completion / template system of Eclipse to wrap any block of code easily.

Here is my template :

```
try { // Wrapp exceptions

${line_selection}${cursor}

} catch (RuntimeException e) { // Forward runtime exception
throw e;
} catch (Exception e) { // Wrap into runtime exception
throw new RuntimeException(
    "Exception wrapped in #${enclosing_method}", 
    e); 
}
```